# performance improvements ideas for partially matching suffix of a string

Tags: postgresql, performance, triggers

I use PostgreSQL 14, and i'm trying to achieve this.

i have `calls` table with `from` and `to` files, i have a system that inserts these rows and it's a lot per second.

i want to add prefixes to that table, for that i have a `prefixes` table that contains `prefix text` and `prefix_length int`, the prefixes can be from 1 to 13 characters length.

so i added the columns `from_prefix` and `to_prefix` and created the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo.bar()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
   NEW.from_prefix=(select p.prefix from prefixes p
                           where NEW.from like (p.prefix || '%')
                           order by p.prefix_length desc limit 1);
   NEW.to_prefix=(select p.prefix from prefixes p
                          where NEW.to like (p.prefix || '%')
                          order by p.prefix_length desc limit 1);
   RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_foo
    BEFORE INSERT  ON calls
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo.bar();
```

and of course i have an index on prefix table on both columns

the problem is that this process is too slow, i can't add it as an after insert trigger because with the amount of rows that are being inserted, it takes too long to find. my prefixes table is about 100k rows.

any ideas regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76172421/4808122) answer is still valid;)

Comment: How fast is it?  How fast does it need to be?

Comment: Is any prefix a prefix of another prefix?